# site:domain.com search doesn't show index page as 1st, how to fix that?

Tags: google-search, search-results

If I enter **site:domain.com** in Google search I see the index page of a site but it doesn't go as #1 result in SERP, but rather 3 or 5th...

What does that mean, why other pages outrank the index page and how to fix that to have my index page ranked as #1 in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home/index page not appearing 1st in a site:search doesnt mean there is something to fix. Please see the comment here >

[How are Google search results ordered when prefixing a search with "site:"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59016/how-are-google-search-results-ordered-when-prefixing-a-search-with-site/59022#59022)

> For example, while the homepage is often first, it doesn't have to
>   be, and it's not a sign that something is broken on the website when
>   it isn't. A site:-query without keywords is a very undefined query, so
>   I wouldn't expect anything particular all the time